# AWSSDK.S3 TransferUtility.Upload files always end up in root

Tags: amazon-s3

I am using AWSSDK.S3 with c#.net trying to upload a file into an existing folder on S3

```
oTransferUtility.Upload("C:\\junk\\fae123.png", strBucket, "Media\\Cache\\f\\fae123.png");
```

Afterwards I get a S3FileInfo for the file

```
var oS3FileInfo = new S3FileInfo(oAmazonS3Client, strBucket, "Media\\Cache\\f\\fae123.png");
```

When I check the `Exists` property it is false, when I inpect the bucket I find the file in the root instead of in the folder.

I know I am contructing the file path correctly (aka key) because I can find existing files already in the folder. e.g.

```
var oS3FileInfo = new S3FileInfo(oAmazonS3Client, strBucket, "Media\\Cache\\f\\abc546.png");
```

When I check the `Exists` property it is true.

Has anyone seen this problem?

---

I have also tried the following with no success, it also dumps all uploads into root

```
TransferUtilityUploadRequest oTransferUtilityUploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest();

oTransferUtilityUploadRequest.FilePath = "C:\\junk\\fae123.png";
oTransferUtilityUploadRequest.Key = "Media\\Cache\\f\\fae123.png";
oTransferUtilityUploadRequest.BucketName = existingBucketName;

oTransferUtility.Upload(oTransferUtilityUploadRequest);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in AWS, however I have found the solution.

Explicitly create the S3 folder if missing

```
S3DirectoryInfo oDirectory = new S3DirectoryInfo(oAmazonS3Client, strBucket, "Media\\Cache\\f\\");
if (!oDirectory.Exists)
    oDirectory.Create();
```

Open an S3 file from the S3 directory object, it doesn't matter if the file does not exist yet, it will get created when you write to it.

```
3FileInfo oS3FileInfo = oDirectory.GetFile("fae123.png");
using (System.IO.Stream stmTargetFileS3 = oS3FileInfo.OpenWrite())
{
    using (System.IO.Stream stmLocalFile = System.IO.File.OpenRead("C:\\junk\\fae123.png"))
        stmLocalFile.CopyTo(stmTargetFileS3);
}
```

This works and the `LastWriteTime` updates correctly on overwritten files.